# How to get fixed position Div to inherit or have min-width of x px? No jQuery solutions

Tags: javascript, html, css

1.I am trying to get a fixed position div (#externalPopupHeader) to inherit the width of its parent width(#reportsWrap) with no success.

2 I am also trying to get the #externalPopupHeader div with the lengthy content to scroll horizontally WITHOUT the scroll bar being visible.  This is required because I would then Like to use javascript to sync the column headings with the content below.

```
#reportsWrap{
 min-width: 1050px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative
}
 #externalPopupHeader{
 width: inherit // Have aslo tried min-width: 1050px, and width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0
 overflow-x: scroll // hidden disables the scrolling.
 }



 <div id="reportsWrap">
    <div id="externalPopupHeader">
          <div id="genConfigFieldsWrap">
              <div class="genField">Record No.</div>
              <div class="genField">Serial Number</div>
              <div class="genField">Room Number</div>
              <div class="genField">Codec IP</div>
              <div class="genField">Model</div>
              <div class="genField">Version</div>
              <div class="genField">NTP Status</div>
              <div class="genField">Speaker Track</div>
              <div class="genField">Max RX Kbps</div>
              <div class="genField">Max TX Kbps</div>
              <div class="genField">Default Call Kbps</div>
              <div class="genField">Remote View</div>
              <div class="genField">Voice VLAN</div>
              <div class="genFieldTrans">Transport</div>
              <div class="genField">Olson Zone</div>
              <div class="genField">Time Zone</div>
              <div class="genField">Helpdesk</div>
              <div class="genField">Provisioning</div>
         </div>

    </div>
    <div id="innerReportWrap">
        <div id="genConfigAnchor">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `#externalPopupHeader{width: 100%;}`?

Comment: yes. didn't work either

Comment: Also may be a case that a number of styles in your css files do not have `;` at the end of each style property. Add ; to end of each style.

Answer (score 0):

your code is ok. your div data is to small to check the original behavior.

try to add some more text to check.

```
<div class="genField">NTP Status NTP Status NTP Status NTP Status</div>
```

then you will see that it is correct.

you can check this example

```
https://jsfiddle.net/r61t50sb/1/
```